# how do I use hook_services_request_postprocess_alter() to wrap field with CDATA?

Tags: 7, views, services

May i know how to use "hook_services_request_postprocess_alter" .I have field called 'body' in $result ,I want to wrap it with `CDATA`.Any idea how to do it? `&$result[0]->body` is my variable.

```
function hook_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, &$result) {

watchdog("custom_forms", '<pre>' . print_r(&$result[0]->body, true) . '</pre>');
}
```

I created a view of service display and body is one of the field,which i want to wrap it with cdata,in order to avoid encoding problem,can anybody help me in this? OR **Which other hook function I need to use in order to avoid encoding problem with body field,when i view page source of service url?** In view page source of service url `&lt &gt` are coming instead of `><` for body field.

Answer (score 0):

This code work for you to over right body result.

```
function hook_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, &$result) {
  if (is_object($result)){
    //Single value
    $tmpSArray = (array) $result;
    if (!empty($tmpSArray)){
      foreach ($tmpSArray as $skey => $sval){
        $result->body = t('<![CDATA['.$result->body.']]>');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I updated my code, but if i hit service url and view page source, i cannot see 'cdata' and body html field is not encoded, it has &lt,&gt etc instead of  > <

Comment: use t() instead of it.

Comment: i can see body content wrapped with CDATA now, but encoding problem is not solved. Do u know which hook function i need to use in order to avoid encoding problem in view page source?